# Jmeter global properties and Simple Data Writers

Tags: jmeter

I am setting a Jmeter global property on the command line with the -G option. I try to use this property to alter the file name of a Simple Data Writer. However, In the data writer the __P function returns only the default.

```
jmeter -t ... --nongui ... -GFileName=MyFile.xml ...
```

So, I know that I am setting the global property correctly. Both the jmeter log and the Jmeter server log show that the value is being captured from the command line. However it still refuses write a file name with anything other than the default.

I use the following command

```
filename_${__P(FileName,Default.fl)}
```

How do I pass in a value at the command line so that I can use it as the file name for a Simple Data Writer?

Notes: I am using remote servers, so I must use -G, and I already have a primary data file output, so I cannot use -l .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use **-J** or **-D** directives to set your property?

---

Everything will work as you want in case of

```
-JFileName=MyFile.xml
```

or

```
-DFileName=MyFile.xml
```

In both the cases you can than further refer to this property in Simple Data Writer as `${__P(FileName,)}`.

Well, I've got the same negative result as your while trying to use global (-G) property but I cannot find in your situation described any prerequisites to use global (-G) properties instead of local (-J) or system (-D) ones.
Global properties are defined to be sent to remote servers... are you executing test in client-server mode (jmeter-server started)?

---

Than, as per  [18.3.9 Simple Data Writer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer)

> When running in non-GUI mode, the -l flag can be used to create a data file.

I.e. running

```
jmeter -n -t ... -l MyFile.xml
```

will give you the same result in MyFile.xml.

---

As additional note.
You can try to use [JMeterPlugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) solutions:
[Flexible File Writer](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter) - instead of native Simple Data Writer.

Comment: These are all great points. I am indeed using remote servers, and I already have a primary output file.